# Firebase function failed to load | request to 127.0.0.1:8225/__/functions.yaml failed, reason socket hung up

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am trying to run my firebase function using `firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions`

And this is what it logs

```
[debug] [2023-08-14T10:45:19.338Z] Failed to call quitquitquit. This often means the server failed to start request to http://localhost:8825/__/quitquitquit failed, reason:  {"message":"request to http://localhost:8825/__/quitquitquit failed, reason: ","type":"system","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"ECONNREFUSED"}
[error] ⬢  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FetchError: request to http://127.0.0.1:8825/__/functions.yaml failed, reason: socket hang up {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"Failed to load function definition from source: FetchError: request to http://127.0.0.1:8825/__/functions.yaml failed, reason: socket hang up"}}
[info]
```

It seems a request is failing.